# Add column based on primary key

Tags: r

I have two tables where the 'ENSG' and 'Ensembl Gene ID' columns are primary keys. I'm interested in combining the `average raw counts` column to the first table based on matching primary keys.

| Condition | ENSG | avg_rep |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Untreated | ENSG00000281593 | 8.702268e-06 |
| Treated | ENSG00000280987 | 5.444327e-06 |

| Ensembl gene id | average raw counts |
| --- | --- |
| ENSG00000281593 | 3.635470e-04 |
| ENSG00000280987 | 4.558828e-04 |

The end result looks something like this:

| Condition | ENSG | avg_rep | average raw counts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Untreated | ENSG00000281593 | 8.702268e-06 | 3.635470e-04 |
| Treated | ENSG00000280987 | 5.444327e-06 | 4.558828e-04 |

Answer (score 1):

Using `merge`:

```
merge(df1, df2, by.x="ENSG", by.y="Ensemble gene id")
```

Or, as mentioned by Onyambu, using `full_join`:

```
full_join(df1, df2, c('ENSG'='Ensemble gene id'))
```

Where df1 is your first table, and df2 the second one

Comment: Also include the full join code

Comment: What do you mean? @Onyambu

Comment: `full_join(df1, df2, c('ENSG'='Ensemble gene id')`

Answer (score 1):

I think left_join() might do the trick.

```
library(tidyverse)

data_left <- data.frame(
  condition = c('untreated', 'treated'),
  ensg = c('a123', 'b456'),
  avg_rep = c(1,2)
)

data_right <- data.frame(
  ensg_gene_id = c('a123', 'b456'),
  average_raw_count = c(4,5)
)

result <- data_left %>%
  left_join(
    data_right,
    by = c('ensg' = 'ensg_gene_id')
  )
```